# PHP What is wrong with the MIME type to export Excel sheet?

Tags: php, excel, export, mime

There is an issue with this output. When the user clicks the button, it should spit out an excel sheet. However, for some users, it spits out an HTML page. I have a feeling it has something to do with other users having IE7 instead of IE10. However, this function should work for both.

Please help.

Let me know if you can spot the error:

```
$time = time();
$illegals = array('!', '*', "'", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]", "\"");
if(isset($_GET['ns_title'])) {$filename = str_replace($illegals,"",urldecode($_GET['ns_title'])).".xls"; } else { $filename = "myreport$time.xls"; }
header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");    
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"'); 
header("Expires: 0");

print "$headers\n$data";
```

Comment: what is in the `$headers` and `$data` variables?

Comment: Is this over an ssl connection?

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying two types of `Content-type`'s - stick with `application/octet-stream` or supply the actual Excel content type (See Bastien's answer).

Secondly, what's `$headers` and `$data`? We'll assume you're using those thinking they set the headers - but `header()` already does this.

You could use `readfile($filename)` if it's a real file, or simply echo content that you want to start the browser download.

Comment: My guess would be that $headers is a tsv string containing a set of column headers, and $data is a multi-line tsv string containing the data to write

Comment: The $headers and $data variables are global variables called from a session page. I don't think those are contributing to the exporting issue, but then again, I'm up here asking for help.

Comment: I tried using this as well: header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

Comment: @John - unless your data is an OfficeOpenXML format .xlsx file, then you shouldn't be using `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`; if your data is a BIFF format .xls file, then `application/vnd.ms-excel` is the correct mime type; but I'm pretty sure that your data is neither

Comment: Following up on this: browsers have their own configuration on how to handle XYZ filetypes. You can only provide what filetype the browser can expect - it'll handle it however it wants/configured for the provided type in the header.

Answer (score 0):

try this official MIME type `application/vnd.ms-excel`